# iPhone and FB: Can we get FB friend's list with email addresses?

Tags: php, iphone, facebook

I am co-developing an app with an ios programmer. In our app there is a feature of Share Topic, in which we would like to show the list of Facebook friend (which is already done) but as per my ios programmer its not possible to get the Facebook friends list.

Any ideas? If it is not then is it possible to get it from PHP (web-services) end?

---EDIT BEGIN----
And maybe if not possible to get email addresses, then can we send private messages to those friends? Is this would be possible?
---EDIT END----

Any helpful thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your iOS Developer is wrong.

FriendLists can be accessed via the `FriendList` object endpoint ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/)). Note that this functionality requires the `read_friendlists` permission.

As a side note: anything that can be acheived via the GraphAPI can be done with the iOS SDK.

Example:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friendlists" andDelegate:self];
```